# attempting to only print certain letters of a string

Tags: python, list

I've been trying to make a script that includes a piece that only outputs certain letters of the string. so far i've got it to output the first letter but then it gets stuck saying "list index out of range". if you could help that would be great!

code:

```
    lookingfor = right_guesses
    right_guess_length = len(right_guesses)
    word_len = len(word)
    for c in range(0, word_len):
        if word[c] == right_guesses[i]:
            print(word[c], end="")
        elif word[c] == " ":
            print(" ", end="")
        else:
            print("-", end="")
        i +=1
```

Comment: Make sure length of `word` and `right_guesses` is same

Comment: word and right_guesses

Comment: also define `i=0` before for loop

Comment: please, always provide examples, what is word, i and right_guesses

Comment: If it's a hangman game, you might want to look at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations

Answer (score 0):

You could `zip()` up `word` and `right_guesses` in order to compare them:

```py
for c,g in zip(word, right_guesses):
    if c == " ":
        print(" ", end="")
    elif c == g:
        print(c, end="")
    else:
        print("-", end="")
```

Comment: quamrana helped loads, but it's now in the wrong place and won't deal with multiple letters, the word i am using for test purposes is "antidisestablishmentarianism", any ideas?

Comment: Ok, so that's an example of the contents of `word`. What is in `right_guesses`?

Answer (score 0):

This line will give you error.

```
if word[c] == right_guesses[i]:
```

You have not given any value to variable i and using it as an index. Plus it will not iterate your list, it is just a single value.
I recommend this(considering your objective):

```
if word[c] in right_guesses:
```

That should do.